# Load data to a file in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to simply write some text to a .txt file (on mac) when a button is pressed in the HTML. This is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<form style="margin-top:70px;" align=center action="write.php" method="post">       
    <input type="submit" value="Write"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
$stringData = "First\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Second\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

All files are in the same directory but nothing appears in the text file. Whats wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Fred-ii-, are you sure about the 2nd fwrite? that doesn't make sense. The file is still opened, and you're continuing with writing.

Comment: I suggest you check for error conditions in your code.  For example, `fopen` can fail -- you should check for that condition and then determine why it failed.  Programming 101.

Comment: Checking [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)  return value would really help to find a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested**

Change this line

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
```

to

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
```

The file's variable was mismatched.

You can also use the following for error checking.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off
```

In conjunction with:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Couldn't open file for writing!");
```

and

```
fwrite($fh, $stringData) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");
```

---

**You may also want to add an `if` condition to prevent premature writing.**

### PHP handler

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Couldn't open file for writing!");
$stringData = "First\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");
$stringData = "Second\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");
fclose($fh);

if($fh) {
echo "Data successfully written to file.";
}

}
else {
echo "You cannot do that from here.";
}
?>
```

### HTML Form

(Added `name="submit"` to the submit button)

```
<form style="margin-top:70px;" align=center action="write.php" method="post">       
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Write"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen You're welcome. Now as to why it doesn't work, I find that very strange. I pre-tested this and it worked for me. Are you sure your file permissions are set correctly?